# above div float over the below div without styling the below div

Tags: html, css

I need to place the first div over the below div.First div contains a png image and second div contains a background texture.

The problem is the second div is in footer and that is common for other pages also.And that was in seperate php file and was included. So I can't able to edit the second div.
How can I achieve this by only styling the first div?

```
            <div style="">
                <img src="sample.png">
            </div>
            <div style="background-image: url('bg.jpg');">

            </div>
```

below div is in another php file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overlap two html element then you have to use position absolute in css you can write css something like this

```
.firstdiv
{
  position :absolute;
  top: 20px;  /* as per your design you can change it */
}
```